# How to change Bootstrap column width to another size responsively?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically I have something like

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
stuff
</div>
```

and I want it to change to something like

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
stuff
</div
```

So I essentially want to take a div that's placed on the left and move it to the center and widen the column size when the viewport width is <768px. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) from their site.

You can define multiple classes for the different breakpoints. If I understand you correctly you need something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">stuff</div>
```

This translates to: 3 columns on small devices (>= 768px) and 8 columns + 2 offset columns for extra small devices (< 768px). They also have `col-md` and `col-lg-` classes.

Comment: Totally skipped that part where you can assign two column sizes. For my actual code I used <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> and that worked how I originally wanted it to be. Thanks!